Share button not working on Youtube video inside WKWebView iOS
I am loading youtube video inside WKWebView, but its share button is not working on some iPhone.
let preferences = WKWebpagePreferences()
preferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true // Enable JavaScript
webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webConfiguration.defaultWebpagePreferences  = preferences

webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
webView.uiDelegate = self
webView.navigationDelegate = self

Loading youtube video inside webview.
let videoId = "3qBXWUpoPHo"
// Embed YouTube video using iframe
let htmlString = """
    <html>
        <body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
                <iframe width="80%" height="30%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoId)?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </body>
    </html>
"""

// Load HTML string into the WebView
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)

Screenshot
Is this bug related to WKWebView?
I tried adding delegate method of WKNavigationDelegate
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    
    guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        return
    }
    
    if url.absoluteString.hasPrefix("https://twitter.com") || url.absoluteString.hasPrefix("https://facebook.com") {
        // Open the URL in Safari or a system video player
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        decisionHandler(.cancel) // Cancel loading the URL in the WKWebView
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}


Try to be more precise about "not working on some iPhone."
